# Помогите пожалуйста понять почему такой результат

Tags: javascript, scope, context, замыкания

```
(function foo(i) {
    console.log(i);
    if (i === 3) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        foo(++i);
        console.log(i);
    }
}(0));
```

Вывод:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   3
>   2
>   1

Не понимаю откуда 3, 2, 1 и почему они выводятся в конце?

Answer (score 3):

Все достаточно просто. В предложении с `else` отсутствует предложение с return, а имеется переход на предложение с выводом на консоль

```
(function foo(i) {
    console.log(i);
    if (i === 3) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        foo(++i);
        console.log(i);
    }
}(0));
```

Каждый вызов функции печатает сначала исходное значение аргумента, а затем это же значение аргумента, увеличенное на 1.

Поэтому внутри первого вызова функции будет напечатано

```
0 и 1
```

внутри второго вызова будет напечатано

```
1 и 2
```

внутри третьего вызова будет напечатано

```
2 и 3
```

внутри четвертого вызова будет напечатано только 3

```
3
```

так как присутствует предложение return

```
    if (i === 3) {
        return;
    }
```

Если теперь вложить вызовы функций внутрь друг друга, то вы и получите указанный результат.

```
0 1 2 3 3 2 1
| | | | | | |
| | |___| | |
| |_______| |
|___________|
```

Чтобы было более понятно, то замените предложение с вызовом функции

```
foo(++i);
```

га предложение

```
++i;
```

В результате вы получите такую функцию

```
(function foo(i) {
    console.log(i);
    if (i === 3) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        //foo(++i);
        ++i;
        console.log(i);
    }
}(0));
```

и посмотрите, что она выведет в результате работы.

Comment: Мне казалось по такой схеме должно выйти 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3

Comment: @S.Sumyilo Между значениями 0 и 1 вы должны вставить тот вывод, который породит вызов функции, который расположен между выводами этих двух значений.

Comment: @S.Sumyilo Параметры функции образуют область видимости внутри функции.